# How can i use symfony logger to write data in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the separate database mysql table with fields like

`Message ---type ------date`

I want to alog all messages like error , info , waring in database so that i can see the past history of the site and also in case of some problem. i can see whats going on

How can i do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write custom monolog handler.
For details check those links [doctrine monolog handler issue](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/55) and the official documentation [extending monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/04-extending.md)

Comment: I have read https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/extending.md tutorial but i could not get what do i need to put in config.yml file.